# Do EDI and the Geth survive in the "red" ending?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Do EDI and the Geth die at the end of the game if you choose to destroy the Reapers? (In case you let the Geth live in the first place, of course.) Or the only option to keep them alive is to choose one of the other endings?

EDIT:
I've read the answers and if all synthetics are destroyed, how it is possible that Shepard manages to survive and the Normandy keeps flying (at least long enough to crash-land on some planet)? I mean is the destruction of EDI/the Geth certain or only assumed?

Comment: RE: edit, don't bother thinking about it, the ending is a giant magic cop-out.

Comment: You killed the Geth? You monster.

Answer (score 5):

No, all the synthetics will be destroyed, which infortunately include EDI, the Geths and any other AI. 
Indeed if you want to keep them alive, You'll have to choose either Control or Synthesis

> Which implies your own death....

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to destroy the Reapers,

> you will destroy *all* synthetic life. This includes the Geth, EDI, and Commander Shepard (assuming you don't get the 'secret' ending).

Comment: In fact no,
SPOIL!!

in the 'Ending+ Sheppard is supposed to be alive as [you can see here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prohgapL54Q)

Comment: I don't even know what the ending+ is. Is that from NG+? If so, I haven't done that yet.

Comment: It happens if it's your second play through of mass effect 3 or if you have imported a save from the previous one. But in both case, you need to have a very very high war asset level.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that EDI as an AI survives, but the physical form is destroyed - as an AI is just data/program that can talk with some other functions.

Also, all the Geth are destroyed. They are synthetic data hubs that don't run most of their systems on a data core.

PS: The Normandy goes through the hole in the blast, and so it is not affected.

PPS: EDI is the Normandy, so if the Normandy lives, she lives. Simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

My ending on ME3 was the one where I destroy the reapers.

I believe that EDI might have died, as when I look at the scene where the love interest hesitates to put Shepard's name on the wall I looked closely at that wall and saw EDI's name on that wall.

That's why I believe EDI and the Geth may have been killed along with the reapers.

If any information states that EDI and the Geth survived the destroy option then Bioware is holding the information very tightly...

Answer (score 0):

EDI's body will be destroyed but not her data base, meaning she still exists but not in her form she took from Dr. Eva. The Geth, sadly because Legion was my absolute favorite of Mass Effect 2, are more then likely gone unless Legion's sacrafice made them more then just synthetics. Which honestly, would be great. Why doesn't BioWare tell us anything dammit?

Answer (score -4):

It really depends on how you interprete the endings. If you believe that the ending given was the true ending, then EDI and the geth were destroyed along with the reapers. However, if you believe that Shepard was indoctrinated and the ending was really just an illusion created by the reapers in order to break Shepard's will, then there is a possibility that EDI and the Geth survive. It would make sense for the Reapers to make it seem like resisting them would kill EDI and the Geth, due to the possible attachtment that Shepard can have to both. Personally, I find the Indoctrination theory a lot more convincing then just believing that the ending was the true ending. There is a lot of evidence to support the theory, not just in the third game, but throughout the entire series. There is a good You Tube Video that does an excellent job of explaining it, and I highly suggest watching it if you are interested.

Comment: I wish there was a way to filter out all ME3 answers containing the words "Indoctrination theory"

Comment: -1 This is speculative

Comment: All answers are speculative. No one really knows what the endings were supposed to mean. Obviously by your comment you don't favor the Indoctrination theory. You probably SPECULATE that the endings were true, which is fine by the way, everyone is free to intreprete how they will. All I was saying was that you really don't know what happens to EDI and the Geth. No one does. That means the only possibly way to answer Gh0st's question is by giving your interpretation of the ending. My interpretation just happened to involve the theory.

Comment: @Mr.Implacatus Actually I can see Bioware adopting the Indoctrination Theory. Speculative answers and the fact that Bioware will address the ending could make this answer out-of-date quickly.

Comment: As conspiracy theories go this one has roughly as much credibility as chemtrails or 9/11 as an inside job, and both of those have extensive youtube videos where the narrators handpick specific scenes out of context to make them support their point and ignore everything else. It's not proof, it's confirmation bias.